# Checking if an ELF file is truncated

Tags: c, elf

I am trying to get the size of a file using the elf informations to check if the file is not truncated.
What I am dooing right now is comparing the size of the file using `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)` with the size of `(all sections + elf->e_ehsize + (elf->e_phnum * elf->e_phentsize) + (elf->e_shnum * elf->e_shentsize))` but, this doesn't seem correct. Do you guys have any idea on how to know if the elf file is truncated ?

edit: i am only allowed to use the glibc

Comment: Sometimes, a truncated ELF file might be usable (e.g. could be `execve`-d).... You might parse the ELF file with some library like [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/english.html)

Comment: i forgot to add that i am not allowed to use other libs than the glibc (it's a school project)

Comment: On Solaris used to be `signelf` utility, which checked, I think, ELF and generated signature. You might want to look at it at some Open Solaris distribution

Comment: It's best to show your actual code for size computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am dooing right now is comparing the size of the file ... with the size of `(all sections + elf->e_ehsize + (elf->e_phnum * elf->e_phentsize) + (elf->e_shnum * elf->e_shentsize))` but, this doesn't seem correct.

You may be ignoring section alignment. You need to pay attention to `sh_offset` in addition to `sh_size`.